# How to deploy the backend when deploying a flutter base mobile application?

Tags: flutter, nlp

I am planning to develop a mobile application(android/iOS or both) as a final year project. Flutter framework is what I am thinking of using. I have not used the Flutter framework before. But I want to get an idea about the backend. And NLP has to be used for this application. I need an idea on how to develop this application.

Need an idea about the backend. With the Flutter framework.